# What is the command to change the 'System clock synchronized:' setting from 'no' to 'yes' in photon os

Tags: linux, vmware, time, ntp, clock

I have a VM running Photon OS 3.0. NTP is not configured and it is using the hardware clock.
It has fallen out of sync. The hardware clock `hwclock` is in sync with the hypervisor time, but when I run `date` it is not in sync with the hardware.

When I run `timedatectl` it is showing `System clock synchronized: no`

what is command/process to change this to `System clock synchronized: yes`

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Thu 2023-11-02 23:11:03 UTC
           Universal time: Thu 2023-11-02 23:11:03 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 2023-11-02 23:09:29
                Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the `hwclock` time into system time (= displayed by `date`), the most straightforward command to do that would be

```
hwclock --hctosys --utc --noadjfile
```

**Note** that this will change system time backwards, which can be bad for databases and other applications that care about the correct ordering of timestamps.

If you must make this change while applications are running, a safer way would be to use `ntpdate -B <NTP server address>` to gently "slide" the system clock to the correct time.

But any of the above will not change the `System clock synchronized` indication at all.

---

The `System clock synchronized` comes from the kernel's timekeeping status bits: when a NTP service is running and has successfully synchronized the system clock to a NTP time source, it will flip the appropriate bits in the kernel's `time_status` word using the [`adjtimex(2)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html). The `System clock synchronized` is a direct interpretation of the appropriate `time_status` bits by `systemd-timedated`.

In a regular Linux system, you *technically* could install the optional [`adjtimex` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/8/adjtimex) and then use `adjtimex -S 0` to set the kernel's `time_status` word manually to the state it would normally have when NTP synchronization is in effect; but I **cannot recommend this** because it would be effectively just lying to yourself and your system.

Also, [it appears the Photon OS may not have the `adjtimex` command/package available for it](https://github.com/vmware/photon/tree/master/SPECS) anyway, so the practical answer might as well be "you cannot do it without configuring NTP."

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was causing it. The `Synchronize Time with Host` setting in vcenter was unchecked for some reason. Had it enabled and `System clock synchronized` setting changed to `yes` on the VM

[image: Snapshot from Vcenter]

[image]